# Сколько будет один день в секундах?

Tags: php

Сколько будет один день в секундах?
В общем мне надо к time() прибавить один день?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $dayTime = 60*60*24;
```

Comment: Интересно, если в этот день (в данном месте) был переход на летнее/зимнее время, то как надо считать ?

Comment: Это довольно сложно... Простой причиной тому есть то, что далеко не во всех странах этот переход вообще осуществляется и не в один и тот-же промежуток времени.

В данном конкретном случае это не будет столь важно т.к. задача добавить сутки к вызову time().

В общем же случае - всего все-равно не предусмотришь =)

Comment: Что переход в разных странах (в разные периоды истории) по разному - это понятно. 

Вопрос вот в чем, например, если 10 октября 19хх года в 2.00 был переход на зимнее время, то (насколько я помню) стрелки переводятся на час назад (т.е. вместо 2.00 на часах (опять !!!) 1.00). 

Продолжительность этого дня (10 октября) стала 25 часов ?

Comment: Да, обычно это или не учитывается вообще, либо пишется конкретное правила с упором на целевую аудиторию.

Еще раз повторюсь - в контексте данной задачи это неважно.

@avp - хотя, я полагаю проблемы преобразования дат решаются на уровне ОС, сами посудите - timestamp это longint, причем общий для всего земного шара, таким образом в дне всегда `60*60*24` секунд...

PS:Вообще никогда настолько глубоко не копал и не задумывался над такими вопросам...

PPS:надеюсь и не прийдеться =)

Comment: Я на практике тоже не занимался, а вот задумываться IMHO никогда не вредно.

Связь между типом longint для timestamp (а что Вы вкладываете в понятие timestamp ? (я всегда считал, что это число секунд от EPOCH)) и "таким образом в дне всегда 60\*60\*24 секунд..." поясните пожалуйста, если не трудно.

Comment: да это число от EPOCH, но это, в то-же время longint, я к тому, что в любой точке земного шара, любое значение времени в timestamp будет одинаковым (во всяком случае в это и заключается идея timestamp), это довольно сложн для понимания, но это должно быть именно так.

Т.е. если, например, вы сохранили значение `time()` в БД, то, насколько я понимаю - для того чтобы узнать значение для другого часового пояса достаточно его изменить в коде.

Как учитываются конкретные страны и перевод на змнее, летнее время я не имею понятия... Да и, откровенно говоря - пока, мне это не интересно